# Is there a .deb install file equivalent of .rpm first time install argument

Tags: linux, installation, debian, rpm, deb

In an .rpm file, there is an option to check whether the current install is the first version to be installed on the current system

i.e. `%pre` and `%post` scripts will be passed an argument equal to 1* also when the last version is erased `%preun` and `%postun` scripts will be passed an argument equal to 0*.  [ref:](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html)

Is there an equivalent thing in the installing of .deb files?  This seems to be pretty obscure and my searches are turning up nothing to very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.deb` scripts, the current version of the package being installed is passed in as argument `$2`. If it's empty, that means there is no version of this package installed.